# Google Functions Exceeding Memory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We have deployed a python function on GCP Functions that basically receives a HTTP POST JSON, and calls for another system to do some processing. This other system returns a JSON, and we send the JSON back to the original caller.

The function works great with 128mb of memory, but after we got a new customer, they are making one call after another to the function, and now GCP throws a memory limit exceeded error and breaks the process.

I realize that if the customer waits a few min between the calls, the memory goes back down, but I cant ask them to do it.

My question is, is there a way to prevent this massive memory increase after various sequential calls to the function? Or any alternative to detect its getting to the limit and send back a timeout error?

Part of my code

```
#!venv/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, Response,jsonify,make_response
import json
import requests
from functools import wraps
import hashlib
from google.cloud import firestore
import datetime



app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'NOTHERE'

def check_auth(username, password): 
    pwd = hashlib.sha1(str(password).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    db = firestore.Client()

    users_ref = db.collection('XXX')
    doc_ref = users_ref.document(username)
    try:
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        dic = doc.to_dict()
        return pwd == dic['password']
    except:
        pass 

    return False

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Please Login', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

#main function that google calls
@requires_auth
def brokering(request):
    db = firestore.Client()
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ......... here I do some write/reads on the firestore db
```

Memory graph until it breaks(130 calls)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak.  You shouldn't run out of memory under pressure as long as your function doesn't persist things in global memory.

Comment: I moved `db = firestore.Client()` outside, and looks like its working better.... will update soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move as much as possible outside the function. For example, you're currently creating two `firestore.Client()` instances, one in the `brokering` and one in `check_auth`, for every single request. You should move this outside your function definitions, and reuse a single client instance inside the functions.

You're also doing some unnecessary stuff, like initializing an entire Flask app that is unused by Cloud Functions, but cuts into your memory overhead.

I'd rewrite your entire function to be something like this:

```
from flask import request, Response
from functools import wraps
import hashlib
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()
users_ref = db.collection('XXX')

def check_auth(username, password): 
    pwd = hashlib.sha1(str(password).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    doc_ref = users_ref.document(username)

    try:
        return pwd == doc_ref.get().to_dict()['password']
    except:
        pass 

    return False

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Please Login', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@requires_auth
def brokering(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ... # here I do some write/reads on the firestore db
```

Comment: I removed the flask app and put the client outside the function... now it is stable at 70mb :) tks

Comment: No problem! Make sure to remove unnecessary imports as well.

Comment: @DustinIngram  I am fixing a similar problem. Keeping
users_ref = db.collection('XXX') inside the function also causes a significant memory issue ? or was this moved outside the function for convenience only?

Comment: @zd5151 Depends entirely on your use case, but it's likely you don't need to get that reference every time the function is called.